# PayPal initial_fail_amount_action and max_fail_attempts on recurring payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I'm trying to know what is the effect of setting `initial_fail_amount_action` and `max_fail_attempts` when you create a recurring payment plan.

First of all I'd like to know how often a retry is executed because in the PayPal documentation does not say nothing about that. For example, if you define a `max_fail_attempts` to 3, what does it mean? Paypal tries every hour, every day the payment? What is the interval? What is the final status if the whole payments fail? Cancelled or Suspended?

Then, I'd like to know what happen if I set the `initial_fail_amount_action` to `CONTINUE`. In the documentation I've found that PayPal **add the failed payment amount to the outstanding balance due**. What does it mean? Does the subscription remain pending or what is the final status?

Finally, what is the IPN notification do I receive after `max_fail_attempts` reached?

Thank you so much!

PD: I've added this question [on github](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-REST-API-issues/issues/34#issuecomment-394980896) as well.

Comment: Did you ever get any answers? I'm looking to configure `max_fail_attempts = 3` on all recurring payments, but have subscription cancel if the very first payment fails. Doc is not clear if first payment will be tried 3 times too even with `initial_fail_amount_action= CANCEL`.

Comment: I think it's ok. When you configure `initial_fail_amount_action` to cancel you're saying that after the first payment (initial, not recurring) the subscription will be cancelled if the payment fails. `max_fail_attemps` I think that it's related to the recurring payments So after 3 failed attempts the subscription will be cancelled. But, I agree with you, the documentation is not clear.